# /etc/environment: /root: Permission denied

Tags: environment-variables, dpkg

Whenever I run `apt install` to install a package it fails. I get this output at the bottom. It seems to go fine until it asks for permission (`[y/n]`) then is immediately followed by this output, everytime. I do it as root always, I have changed ownership of /etc/environment so everyone can write to it. when I run `dpkg --configure install-info` (like apt seemingly does, and fails) I get just the same output.

```
Setting up install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-6) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 1: /etc/environment: /root: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

edit: my /etc/environment file is empty other than a line where I set my path variable.

Comment: please add the output of `cat /etc/environment` to your question.  Don't reply with this info in a comment, edit your question.  BTW, `/etc/environment` should have 644 permissions.  It should **not** be writable by everyone.

Comment: BTW...just in case `/etc/environment` contains any sensitive/confidential info like passwords - replace them with XXXXXXXXXXX or similar.  anonymising hostnames and usernames etc is also fine, as long as the structure of the file is intact.

Comment: done have much to share, my environment file is empty except for 1 line I added. should this not be the case?

Comment: the exact details of the 1 line you added may be crucial.  or not.  I have no way of knowing - you haven't actually posted the contents of your `/etc/environment` file, you've only described it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is clearly a syntax error in `/etc/environment`. Maybe a stray space, it's impossible to tell for sure from the error message alone. Just fix that error. You say you're setting `PATH`; the `PATH=…` line shouldn't have any spaces in it. The path separator is a colon `:`.

The syntax of `/etc/environment` is just `VARIABLE=VALUE`, you can't use shell quoting there (`/etc/environment` is normally read by [pam_env](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_env), not by a shell).

---

Change the permissions back to allow only root to write to this file. Allowing other users to write to it completely breaks any system security and is completely pointless. Each user can put their own similar settings in `~/.pam_environment`.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my /etc/environment file. it had a ~ at the top. I'm new to vim.